# Lambda Python Error: Runtime exited with error: signal: segmentation fault (core dumped) Runtime.ExitError

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Lately I've had this problem when running my lambdas on aws.
I have checked that the lambda does not run, the lambda starts but does not run.
I tried to increase the memorySize of the lambda but it is not the problem. I leave you an image of the output in cloudwatch.
Thanks in advance.

```
Error: Runtime exited with error: signal: segmentation fault (core dumped) Runtime.ExitError
```

[image]

Comment: What is your development environment?

Comment: python 3.7, deployment with serverless framework 2.71.0

Comment: You don't provide anywhere near enough information to answer this question. What libraries are you using in your Lambda? What is happening just before the segmentation fault? If you don't know, you need to add some logging.

Comment: Not really enough info here to know but If you have libraries that rely on c++ they cannot be packaged on a non linux system then deployed to lambda.

Comment: You have to provide full lambda code and information on how to reproduce the error.

Comment: @LeandroHernándezMira a segfault would be much easier to identify if you add the lambda code as well

Comment: Are you packaging as a .zip or running a docker file? What image are you using in the docker file? Reiterating what others have said, not enough info.

Comment: Are you using Lambda layers? If so, which ones?

Answer (score 2):

One big reason for this `core dumped` error is when your lambda reaches the maximum memory allowed.

You may experience a case where the graph does not show it, and this is still the case.

Comment: If I understand correctly, core dumped is not an error but a diagnostic message. Segmentation fault is the error, and I don't think it can be caused by high memory consumption.

Answer (score 2):

Check your **lambda logic** or **logic runs from a third party dependency**. There may be a memory usage collision which causes `segmentation fault (core dumped)` crash

Answer (score 1):

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)" is the error that Linux prints when
> a program exits with a SIGSEGV signal and you have core creation
> enabled. This means some program has crashed.
>
> In this case python interpreter has crashed unexpectedly. There are
> only a few reasons this can happen:

- You're using a third-party extension module written in C, and that
  extension module has crashed.
- You're (directly or indirectly) using
  the built-in module ctypes, and calling external code that crashes.
- There's something wrong with your Python installation.
- You've discovered a bug in Python or most probably one of the python's library you are using that you should report.

> Things you can try to fix

- If you have updated the libraries you are using check by downgrading them one by one
- If you are using serverless, upgrade it to latest version
- If you are using node, npm upgrade them to latest version